# Trouble removing elements from multidimensional array using for loop (javascript)

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, splice

I'm banging my noob head against the wall on this one...

I have the following code:

```
var guns2 = 
[
["Model 17", "Glock"],
["Model 19", "Glock"],
["PPQ", "Walther"],
["P2000", "HK"],
["Model 92", "Beretta"],
["Model 34", "Glock"]
]

var gunsMake = function () {
    for (i=0; i<guns2.length; i++){
        var make = guns2[i][1];
            if (make ==="Glock"){
                }
            else {
                guns2.splice(i,1);
                }
        };
    };
gunsMake();
console.log(guns2);
```

The result I get in the console is as follows:

```
[["Model 17", "Glock"], ["Model 19", "Glock"], ["P2000", "HK"], ["Model 34", "Glock"]]
```

What I'd like to see is:

```
[["Model 17", "Glock"], ["Model 19", "Glock"], ["Model 34", "Glock"]]
```

"["P2000", "HK"]" *shouldn't* be there...I have a feeling it has something to do with the "guns2.length" argument in the for loop..it seems like it's skipping the subsequent array every time it splices, but I can't quite wrap my brain around a fix.

Please, someone steer me right :)

Comment: Don't modify an array while you're iterating over it. Insert desired results into a different array.

Comment: Ah, that makes a ton of sense, especially for what I need to achieve in my end goal.  Would "push" be an effective way to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes, `push` is one way to add elements to an array. You need to create a different array first, then `push` to it inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always awful to modify the array in-place. If that's what you decide to do, decrement `i` when you remove an element.

http://jsfiddle.net/kVzLn/

```
var guns2 = 
[
["Model 17", "Glock"],
["Model 19", "Glock"],
["PPQ", "Walther"],
["P2000", "HK"],
["Model 92", "Beretta"],
["Model 34", "Glock"]
]

var gunsMake = function () {
    for (i=0; i<guns2.length; i++){
        var make = guns2[i][1];
            if (make ==="Glock"){
                }
            else {
                guns2.splice(i--,1); // Decrement i here
                }
        };
    };
gunsMake();
console.log(guns2);
```

Comment: Awesome.  For this particular app, I'm probably going to go with Asad's suggestion of pushing to a new array, but you're advice worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It usually isn't a good idea to modify an array while you're iterating over it, since it becomes hard to keep track of indices and exit conditions. Either insert desired results into a separate array, or use the native `filter` method to return a filtered array.

```
var gunsMake = function (guns, desiredMake) {
    return guns.filter(function(v,i,a){
        return v[1] == desiredMake;
    });
};
guns2 = gunsMake(guns2, "Glock");
console.log(guns2);
```

More on the Array `filter` method on MDN: [Array filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Asad, thanks again for your help on this.  I'll give filter a shot--looks like a pretty powerful method.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Yup, no problem. You should take a look at the other Array methods (documented on MDN) as well. Once you're familiar with them, they pretty much obviate the need to use a `for` loop in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You're deleting (splicing) nodes out of your array while you're looping through it with a fixed index.  So, you're not checking all of the elements.

If you check element #1 and decide to delete it, then when you check #2 you're actually checking #3.

Comment: Yeh, that's what I figured (thanks for the confirmation).  I just wasn't sure how to do it properly.